# Using Params in Rails Routes for generating url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a scoped route:

```
 scope :path => ":db", :defaults => {:db => "default"} do
   resources :boxes
 end
```

That generates

```
    boxes GET    /:db/boxes(.:format)          {:db=>"default", :action=>"index", :controller=>"boxes"}
         POST   /:db/boxes(.:format)          {:db=>"default", :action=>"create", :controller=>"boxes"}
 new_box GET    /:db/boxes/new(.:format)      {:db=>"default", :action=>"new", :controller=>"boxes"}
edit_box GET    /:db/boxes/:id/edit(.:format) {:db=>"default", :action=>"edit", :controller=>"boxes"}
     box GET    /:db/boxes/:id(.:format)      {:db=>"default", :action=>"show", :controller=>"boxes"}
         PUT    /:db/boxes/:id(.:format)      {:db=>"default", :action=>"update", :controller=>"boxes"}
         DELETE /:db/boxes/:id(.:format)      {:db=>"default", :action=>"destroy", :controller=>"boxes"}
```

I would like to be able to call boxes_url (for example) and have it infer that the value for :db should be inferred from the current request.

Example:

A request is made for "/lax/boxes".   In the template, I call box_url(@box), and it generates the url "/lax/boxes/1" (where @box.id = 1).

The only solution I currently see is to always include params[:db] in url, calling box_url(params[:db],@box).

Does anyone know anyway to get the behavior I've described?

Answer (score 0):

This (in a helper file) should work:

```
def box_url(box)
    super(params[:db], box)
end
```

Unfortunately, you'll have to repeat this for each url/path you want to override.